# Shared elements between pages in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

I am making an app using Xamarin.Forms, and all the pages have the same "header", which has a photo and two buttons.

I am wondering, is it possible to make a custom element, that I can instantiate in xaml, like I can do with a Button or Label? If it is, what should I check out?

Comment: You can create a custom control and reuse it: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/custom-renderer/view/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to use a ControlTemplate in the ResourceDictionary in Application.Resources in App.xaml. You can define a header/footer/custom theme for your whole app, when you use it. Check this out https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/templates/control-templates/creating/