# Partial View or Master Page for MAUI UI

Tags: maui

Does MAUI have any UI concept similar to a partial view or master page like you have in ASP.NET MVC?  I have one small chunk of UI that I want to be on all pages in my MAUI app (think like a toolbar).  What is the best way to accomplish that in MAUI?

Comment: Maybe ControlTemplate - see https://stackoverflow.com/a/48010348/199364. Should work the same in Maui.